# My loop ignores some matching values when reading from txtfile

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My loop ignores some matching values when reading from txtfile
What I'm trying to do is to read from a file instantly when uploaded from my view. But before I return it to the view I need to find the most used word in txtfile and manipulate it.

Please keep in mind that im new to C#, so I suppose my code is not pretty!

```
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult UploadFile(IFormFile file)
        {
            var result = string.Empty;
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(file.OpenReadStream()))
            {
                result = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }

            List<string> fileContent = string.IsNullOrEmpty(result)
                ? null
                : result.Split(' ', '.', ',', ';', '\\').ToList();

            return View("../Home/Index", findMostUsedWord(fileContent));
        }


        public string findMostUsedWord(List<string> fileContent)
        {
            fileContent = fileContent.Where(str => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str)).ToList();
            fileContent = fileContent.Where(str => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(str)).ToList();
            fileContent = fileContent.Where(str => str.Length >= 4).ToList();

            var mostUsedWord = fileContent.GroupBy(item => item).OrderByDescending(g => g.Count()).Select(g => g.Key).First();
            return processMostUsedWord(mostUsedWord, fileContent);
        }

        public string processMostUsedWord(string mostUsedWord, List<string> fileContent)
        {
            int wordCount = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < fileContent.Count(); i++)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(fileContent[i].ToLowerInvariant());
                if (fileContent[i].ToLowerInvariant() == mostUsedWord.ToLowerInvariant())
                {
                    fileContent[i] = "foo" + fileContent[i] + "bar";
                    Debug.WriteLine("FOUND MATCH");
                    wordCount++;
                }
            }

            ViewData["mostUsedWord"] = "The most common word is " + mostUsedWord + " and it appears " + wordCount + " times";
            return prettyPrint(fileContent);
        }

        public string prettyPrint(List<string> fileContent)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            for (int i = 0; i < fileContent.Count(); i++)
            {
                sb.Append(fileContent[i] + " ");
            }

            return sb.ToString();
        }
```

I know that expected output should be 88 but I only get 73 matches

Any thoughts?

Comment: Your first two `where` clauses are redundant - you only need one of them (and you can combine that with the second one using an `&&`). Also, only call `ToList()` when you've finished building your query, since that method pulls all the data each time.

Comment: Or simplify it: `fileContent = fileContent.Where(str => str?.Trim().Length > 3).ToList();`

Comment: oh thats much nicer, thank you! But it still only gives me a result of 73 aladdin and not 88

Comment: Also, you initially do a case-sensitive comparison in `findMostUsedWord`, but then do a case-insensitive comparison in `processMostUsedWord`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify all your code (and use case-insensitive comparison) by doing:

```
// Split the file text on whitespace and punctuation characters
var fileContent = File
    .ReadAllText(@"f:\private\temp\aladdin.txt")
    .Split(new[] {' ', '\r', '\n', '\t', '.', ',', ';', '\'', '\\', '/'},
        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Where(str => str.Length > 3);

// Get the word and it's count in an anonymous object
var mostUsedWord = fileContent
    .GroupBy(item => item, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)  // case-insensitive compare
    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
    .Select(g => new {Word = g.Key, Count = g.Count()})  // select the word and it's count
    .First();

ViewData["mostUsedWord"] = $"The most common word is '{mostUsedWord.Word}', " + 
    $"which appears {mostUsedWord.Count} times";

// Put the list of strings together, joining them with a space character (prettyPrint):
return string.Join(" ", fileContent);
```

Comment: You beat me to it. I was about to hit `Post Your Answer` with pretty much the same code... :-) ... The only other thing would be to look for situations where there is more than one word that matches the top count.

Comment: That looks so much better, I will compare mine with yours, but I cant figure ut why it only says "The most common word is Aladdin and it appears 73 times" but I know it should be 88 times :/

Is there something wrong with my UploadFile method?

Comment: @RufusL I updated the post, so basically I want to upload a textfile and find the most used word in the file and how many times it occurs

Comment: Yeah, all of the text wont fit in the post :P

Comment: But there's 81 aladdin in that text not just 58 :/

Comment: I updated the sample to include reading the file and splitting on punctuation characters as well as whitespace characters.